# Poor performance on inner join using dates and between

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, performance, join, query-performance

I am having trouble optimizing a query that does an inner join using a date range. The purposes of the query is take daily data and summarize by week.

```
Select  pcw.EndDate WeekEndDate, h.Store, SUM(h.DeliveryChargesTotal) DeliveryChargesTotal 
from Daily_GC_Headers h
inner join PeriodCalendar_Weeks pcw
on h.SalesDate between pcw.StartDate and pcw.EndDate
where SalesDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and isCanceled = 0 
group by pcw.EndDate, h.Store
```

Simplified schema of `Daily_GC_Headers` table (13.8 million rows; about 5.4 million match criteria in WHERE clause):

```
Store - Varchar(10) (PK)
SalesDate - Date (PK)
TicketNumber - SmallInt (PK; starts over 1 each day at each store.)
IsCanceled - Bit
DeliveryChargesTotal - Decimal(9,2)
```

Simplified schema of `PeriodCalendar_Weeks` Table (570 rows; 53 match the criteria):

```
Year - smallint (PK)
Period - tinyint (PK)
Week - tinyint (PK)
StartDate - Date    
EndDate - Date
```

This query takes about **15** seconds in SSMS. Querying `Daily_GC_Headers` by itself (and just grouping by `Store`) takes **2** seconds. A query against `PeriodCalendar_Weeks` is "instant".

`DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS` indicates that the stats are both tables are current (we run a weekly job to update them). I've tried clearing the plan caches.

The execution plan is strange. For example, it is doing an Eager Spool on `PeriodCalendar_Weeks`. The estimated rows is **156.6** but the actual rows is **153,971**. It then filters the results of that first spool and does a Lazy Spool. The estimated/actual rows of that 2nd spool is **5.4** million, *even though the underlying table has less than 600 rows in it.*

What should I be looking for or doing to optimize this?

**Additional Information**

For sake of clarity, I initially described an oversimplified PK on the Weeks table. I have update the schema above to show the full key. The PK described for the Headers is (and was) the full key.

Screen shot of some rows from the Weeks table:
[image]

Stats from the Weeks table:
[image]

Some stats from Headers table. There seems to be an histogram record for about every 5-10 days for the entire history in the table (3 years).
[image]

Comment: Can you attach the plan?  Also, have you run the queries with `set statistics io` and compared logical reads?

Comment: @Mike Fal: The XML of the query plan was too big to post here.

Comment: I guess the `isCanceled` column is in the `Daily_GC_Headers` table, right? Add also in the question the datatypes of the columns and the indexes you have.

Comment: You can post the plan to [answers.sqlperformance.com](http://answers.sqlperformance.com) using [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer). Best option is a non-anonymized **actual** plan. *Disclaimer: I work for SQL Sentry.*

Comment: @MikeFal: Posted to https://answers.sqlperformance.com/questions/1568/why-is-it-doing-a-eager-spool-followed-by-a-lazy-s.html

Comment: Also a couple of observations: (1) matching 5.4 million rows out of 13 million is almost certainly always going to yield a scan (and that's a good thing). (2) if your "week end" is standardized, you might do better aggregating before the join, assuming you can group by datediff(week, some base date) or datediff(day, some base date)/7.

Comment: @ypercube: Yes, its part of Daily_GC_Headers. Added data types.

Comment: What weekdays are your weeks standardized on? Sunday -> Saturday, Monday -> Sunday, something else? Are weeks at year boundaries broken up? How? Can we see a few rows from the calendar table?

Comment: You say the stats look current, but what do the histograms looks like? Is the data skewed?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Posted some rows.

Comment: @MarkWilkinson: I just added a screen-shot of the full historogram of the Weeks table. The Headers table doesn't look skewed to me (but I have no experience ready these).

Comment: (I think the stats from the big table are much more important than the calendar table with 500 rows.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Posted some stats for the big table.

Comment: @poke can you try the query I posted, and see if you get the same results and better performance? And if it generates a recommended index, can you try creating that (ideally on a test system)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much more efficient to do this without having to go back and join to the periods table.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE;

Select @StartDate = Min(StartDate), @EndDate = MAX(EndDate) 
from dbo.PeriodCalendar_Weeks pcw
where (pcw.Year = @Year and pcw.Period < @Period) 
  or  (pcw.Year = @Year and pcw.Period = @Period and pcw.Week <= @Week) 
  or (pcw.Year = @Year -1 and pcw.Period >= @Period);

SELECT 
  WeekEndDate = DATEADD(DAY, 6, DATEADD(WEEK, SalesWeek, @StartDate)), 
  Store, 
  DeliveryChargesTotal = dct
FROM 
(
  SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, SalesDate)/7, Store, SUM(DeliveryChargesTotal)
  FROM dbo.Daily_GC_Headers
  WHERE SalesDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND isCanceled = 0
  GROUP BY DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, SalesDate)/7, Store
) AS x (SalesWeek, Store, dct)
ORDER BY WeekEndDate, Store;
```

A filtered index may help, if many rows exist where `isCanceled = 1` (these are just possible suggestions, depending on cardinality of `Store`, and may not be the most optimal):

```
CREATE INDEX x ON dbo.Daily_GC_Headers
  (SalesDate) INCLUDE (Store, DeliveryChargesTotal)
  WHERE isCanceled = 0;
```

If there are very few rows where `isCanceled = 1`, this may be better:

```
CREATE INDEX x ON dbo.Daily_GC_Headers
  (SalesDate, IsCanceled) INCLUDE (Store, DeliveryChargesTotal);
```

Both are worth trying on a test system, as well as moving `Store` into the key in either case, or moving `IsCanceled` to the `INCLUDE` list in the latter case. On my system, I found the best results with everything but the date in the `INCLUDE` list:

```
CREATE INDEX x ON dbo.Daily_GC_Headers
  (SalesDate) INCLUDE (Store, IsCanceled, DeliveryChargesTotal);
```

Again, you will need to test if any of these work out, or if the query above gives a different/better recommendation directly from SQL Server.

Comment: IsCanceled=1 on at least 95% of the records.

Comment: There are only about ~110 different values for Store so I'd say its pretty low.

Comment: @AaronBertand: This query ran in 2 seconds, which is how fast a straight SELECT...SUM()...GROUP BY is on that table with no join. Execution plan didn't recommend any indexes, though.

Comment: @poke so eliminating the redundant join is better, yes? Is the output different from your slower version of the query, or missing any information?

Comment: Yes, its better. My query was taking 15 seconds. The Week End Date is actually showing the week start date, but I know how to fix that.